# How do I setup/configure a Table to ensure I don't enter duplicate records.

Tags: sql-server, azure

I working with an Azure SQL Database ( Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Dec  5 2016 21:15:30) and I'm trying to configure a table (CHART) so that I will not get any duplicate records. The table structure is as follows:

```
Chart_ID     Primary Key (Identity Key)
Chart_Date   Date
Chart_Code   VarChar   (This is a unique value)
Chart_Value  Int
```

I'm using an Update or Insert if New query.  Currently the table has the following record:

```
 1,  2016-12-10, 12Dec10-00TAM00, 10
```

If I Upsert the following record:

```
0, 2016-12-10, 12Dec10-00TAM00, 10    (Note I use a zero for the primary key so the database will assign the correct primary key)
```

The data base will insert an new record with a Chart_Id = 2, but I don't want it to. To me this is a duplicate record.

I also did a little research and found some information on Unique Constraints.

From what I found I believe I could do something like

```
Use TestDB;
Go
Alter Table CHART
ADD CONSTRAINT AK_UNIQUECHART_CODE UNIQUE (CHART_CODE);
```

What's the best practice for accomplishing the goal of no duplicate records.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some version of [Sam Saffron's upsert method](https://samsaffron.com/blog/archive/2007/04/04/14.aspx).

A rough draft would look something like this:

```
create procedure dbo.Chart_upsert (
    @Chart_ID int          /* not used in this draft */
  , @Chart_Date date
  , @Chart_Code varchar(32)
  , @Chart_Value int
  ) as
begin
  set nocount on;
  set xact_abort on;
  begin tran
    update dbo.Chart with (serializable)
      set   Chart_Value = @Chart_Value
      where Chart_Code  = @Chart_Code
    if @@rowcount = 0
    begin;
      insert dbo.Chart (Chart_Date, Chart_Code, Chart_Value)
        values (@Chart_Date, @Chart_Code, @Chart_Value);
    end;
  commit tran
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a little bit of information missing here, but it sounds like your chart code really is your primary key, unless you are using the surrogate for something. If you are and the chart code is a lookup column you could add a non-clustered unique index there as well.

Changing the primary key to chart-code, using the unique constraint, or the non-clustered unique index would have a similar effect on the inserts as creating a unique constraint, but be aware all inserts that aren't unique fail in this situation, but ihe indexes will potentially have an impact on your query plan, so without knowing what your retrieval pattern looks like it's hard to recommend one of these approaches over the other.

If you are looking to do an upsert efficiently of a large number of these records, I would turn your eye to the MERGE statement of SQL Server.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: Things to be aware of when using `merge`: [Use Caution with SQL Server's `MERGE` Statement - Aaron Bertrand](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) and [UPSERT Race Condition With Merge - sqlteam](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx)

Comment: That's actually a really good point, typically MERGE is best suited for analytical/reporting systems.